# How can i redirect something by the id in a hyperlink in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

The thing is had a button that would do that but i decided it to use an hyperlink, int the code you will see that the button i was using was redirecting me to the team page, in wich the id would give the information that would fill the other fields. Basically i am in the player page and i wantoi it to redirect to the the players team page by the id.

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int playerId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"]);

        DBLPlayers players = new DBLPlayers();
        Player player = players.SelectById(playerId);

    Response.Redirect("DetalhesClube.aspx?Id=" + player.Team.ID.ToString());
}
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

}

How can i use the hyperlink to do this?

Comment: and what's the exact problem ? Doesn't redirect or what ?

Comment: well i am newbie in asp.net and i don't really know how to do this outside a button, i have seen somethings in a hyperlink but it's really vage not much of a help

Comment: In `Page_Load`, check that Id exists in the querystring and, if it does, do the redirect there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is just a matter of UI visualization? Use a `LinkButton` instead... the code behind will remain the same.

Do you prefer to have a direct HTML link to the new page? For each player load also the related team's Id in you aspx page and use it to compose the `<a>` hiperlink.

If you post the aspx code we could be more precise.

Comment: thanks man, the LinkButton will do fine, didn't think of that one.

Comment: @user1336902: you should mark the answer as Accepted if you think it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you wont to use Button then set PostBackUrl property and you will save one server request, like this :

```
Button4.PostBackUrl = "DetalhesClube.aspx?Id=" + player.Team.ID.ToString();
```

But as I can see you don't wont to post any values just link to another page, so it will be better to use plain old href or HyperLink ASP.NET control, you can decorate it to look and act as a button trough [css](http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/).

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "DetalhesClube.aspx?Id=" + player.Team.ID.ToString();
```